# JPA table generating confusion

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

when I tried to use JPA generating mysql tables, the following exception was encountered.

> mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property:
>   com.cs.domain.GISProject.segmentOfProject in
>   com.cs.domain.ProjectSegment.gisProcesses

here are my entity definitions;

**ProjectSegment**

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "segmentOfProject", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<GISProject> gisProcesses;
```

**GISProject**

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn
private transient ProjectSegment segmentOfProject;
```

it seems ok from tutorials, that's why I am confused about what went wrong.

the environment is Spring Boot 2.1.3.RELEASE, with spring-boot-starter-data-jpa and mysql driver 5.1.28

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14618486/jpa-manytomany-transient-collection)

Comment: @buræquete, the problem is my one to many and vise versa annotation is not working as expected. so weird that other one to many fields works

Comment: Can you please add link to the tutorial you've used, and also please add the details of the working relationship?

Comment: absolutely, https://hellokoding.com/jpa-one-to-many-relationship-mapping-example-with-spring-boot-maven-and-mysql/ is the tutorial I followed

Comment: I was referring to your `transient` usage, that should be the issue, since it stops that field to be considered during persistence.

Comment: I was not even get the chance to start any transaction. the spring boot project failed to boot. and tables are not generated

Comment: After dropping `transient` that still happens? Your entities are read and used to generate the relational structure, with one side of a relationship is ignored, your issue is happening IMO

Comment: you are right, I started a new spring project with nothing but entities to test relationship generation. and seems something went wrong beyond my understanding. is there any other thing I can provide for clarify my situation?

Comment: It worked with the `transient` keyword or w/o?

Comment: no transaction was used, no repository, no dao design or service, just entities in the project code

Comment: Yes, but I am talking about the `transient` in `private "transient" ProjectSegment segmentOfProject;` Did you keep that, or dropped it? My point was that just dropping that keyword should've been enough.

Comment: @buræquete, sorry I didn't get you, thanks for your help, it works now. but I am very confused why transient can not be used by field. anyway it works now. thanks again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `transient` keyword in your `@ManyToOne` relationship defining field in `GISProject` entity is causing the issue. As seen from the error message, due to the transience the field is completely ignored for the persistence, and relationship definition is broken from one side. Removing it should be enough.

> **Transient Fields**
>
> Transient entity fields are fields that do not participate in persistence and their values are never stored in the database (similar to transient fields in Java that do not participate in serialization). Static and final entity fields are always considered to be transient. Other fields can be declared explicitly as transient using either the Java transient modifier (which also affects serialization) or the JPA @Transient annotation (which only affects persistence):
>
> ```
> public class EntityWithTransientFields {
>     static int transient1; // not persistent because of static
>     final int transient2 = 0;  // not persistent because of final
>     transient int transient3; // not persistent because of transient
>     @Transient int transient4; // not persistent because of @Transient
> }
> ```
>
> The above entity class contains only transient (non persistent) entity fields with no real content to be stored in the database.

[source](https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/entity/fields)