# JPA Entity class which is not mapped to any table

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, jpql

I am using a entity class for mixing two/three table columns in one entity to hold an outcome of SYS_REFCURSOR in oracle

This allows me to have single class which is not mapped to any table but it still is an Entity

```
@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
class EmployeeDetails {
    @Id
    @Column("emp_id")
    String empId;
    
    @Column("job_name")
    String jobName;

    @Column("dept_name")
    String deptName;

    //Future requirement
    //String updatedBy
}
```

Now I have an additional requirement, to add who last modified the employee table, I don't want modify the procedure now, the procedure is being re-used in another background procedure and batch jobs.

My question is, is it possible to use @ManyToOne on this class which is obviously not mapped to any table

If not how do avoid manually looping a child array list, is there a ready made option in JPA or spring boot to achieve that.

Or what will be the smartest/recommended way to bring the below Entity into this class

```
@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name="app_users")
class AppUsers {

    @Id
    @Column(name="user_id")
    String userId;

    @Column
    String userName;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this is working for you, but is a risk; marking the class as an entity tells JPA it has a table and that JPA must support all read/write operations for it using that table. I'm not sure how you want a ManyToOne to function on a cursor type - it won't be giving a fk for the JPA provider to query and build the object references, is it? How you build that reference class is what will decide how you need to map it. I would look at EclipseLink's Oracle's PL/SQL handling https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/solutions/oracledb002.htm .

Comment: it is working fine and foreign key is not a problem, @joincolumn with attributes can join and generate the join query on the fly, but the problem is in case the class is not mapped to a table there is my question

Comment: Not really - If you expect a FK column to be returned, how you are building these EmployeeDetails is in question, as they are not entities (despite you mapping it as such, you can't be reading them via em.find calls), so are going outside JPA behaviour to build them. You have to show that, and then figure a way to get that build behavior to use your ManyToOne mappings to fetch the referenced data. You might be better off leaving it a basic mapping to the fk value, and then performing your own queries to fetch the referenced AppUsers if/when required.

Comment: If they are built as entities, as I know some setups allow this, you are going to have to figure out provider specifics on how it handles ManyToOne relationships when it controls the query. Hibernate is very keen on table joins, and so might expect app_users data to be returned with the EmployeeDetails rows. Using lazy fetching on the relationship might allow it to fetch the data independently - but many optimizations force such queries to use a table join to avoid the N+1 problem. Batch read queries fetching your AppUsers via an 'in' clause is your best performant bet, but provider specific

Comment: @JoinColumn is working fine as per my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My spring boot 2.6.2 EntityManager code is as follows

```
q = em.createStoredProcedureQuery("MY_PROC",EmployeeDetails.class);
q.registerStoredProcedureParameter("OUT_REFC", void.class, ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR);
q.execute();
q.getResultList()
```

I have modified my class EmployeeDetails as below

```
@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
class EmployeeDetails {
    @Id
    @Column("emp_id")
    String empId;
    
    @Column("job_name")
    String jobName;

    @Column("dept_name")
    String deptName;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(
      name="user_id",
      referencedColumnName="emp_id", 
      insertable=false, 
      updatable=false, 
      nullable=true
    )
    AppUsers updatedBy;
}
```

The log prints Hibernate two times one after one as below, first it calls the proc and then it calls the select query, so, I did not wrote that SQL myself, the JPA layer is taking care of it

```
Hibernate:
  {call MY_PROC(?)}
Hibernate:
  select 
   ...
   ...
  from app_users
 where user_id=?
```

so, my expectation achieved and I am getting the values

Answer (score 0):

@Transient, check how this annotation works it will resolve the issue, you need to understand working of @Transient

Comment: I think transient disables the SQL generation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14618486/jpa-manytomany-transient-collection